# React - Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render with Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component in which I'm calling my custom hook.

The custom hook looks like this:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';

export function useSubscription() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)

  if (loading) return false
  if (error) return null

  return data
}
```

And then the component I'm using it in that causes the error is:

```
export default function Form(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  let theSub = useSubscription();
  if (theSub === false) {
    return (
      <Spinner />
    )
  } // else I'll have the data after this point so can use it.

  useEffect(() => {

    if (!isDeleted && Object.keys(router.query).length !== 0 && router.query.constructor === Object) {
      setNewForm(false);

      const fetchData = async () => {
        // Axios to fetch data
      };

      fetchData();
    }

  }, [router.query]);

  // Form Base States
  const [newForm, setNewForm] = useState(true);
  const [activeToast, setActiveToast] = useState(false);


  // Form Change Methods
  const handleUrlChange = useCallback((value) => setUrl(value), []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (_event) => {
    // Submit Form Code
  }, [url, selectedDuration, included, excluded]);


  return (
    <Frame>
      My FORM
    </Frame>

  )


}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling any hook conditionally?

Comment: Nope - nothing conditional

Comment: Can you share the complete code of `Form` component?

Comment: @Yousaf - I've updated the post with Form cmponent code

Comment: try moving `if (theSub === false) {` just before `return (...)`.

Comment: @Yousaf - don;t understand, without that condition, I'll always get the Spinner

Comment: Ok - if I do `let theSub = useSubscription();` then only `console.log(theSub)`, it shows me the result of my query. However it never logs the middle loading state (which I'd expect to see from a false). I have no idea why its doing that an whether I can be certain that it would always return the final result, and not a loading state

Comment: I think I tangled up in several places, confusing a lot of stuff. Eventually figured out I could use `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)`. The reason why it wasn't wokring at first was because I was setting other varibale names: `const { loadingX, errorX, dataX } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)` - which of course will give me undefined to each. Issue closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect for calling hook at the first time of rendering component.

```
export default function Form(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [theSub, setTheSub] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => { setTheSub(useSubscription()); }, []);
  
  if (theSub === false) {
    return (
      <Spinner />
    )
  } // else I'll have the data after this point so can use it.

  // I have some other states being set and used related to the form e.g:
  // const [whole, setWhole] = useState(true);

  return (... The form ...)
```

Comment: hook can't be called inside useeffect!

Comment: Yep - can't be inside else get `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. `

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Then, what's stopping you to call that hook inside Form component? I mean, you can use useQuery inside Form component.